# Install peerDependencies with a base library

Tags: npm

I have a library which depends on another library that has a bunch of peerDependencies.  I want to include all the peerDependencies in my library so that apps that use it don't have to worry about them.  So they layout is something like this:

```
base-library:
  peerDependencies:
    - a
    - b

my-library:
  dependencies:
    - base-library
    - (a, b)

app:
  dependencies:
    - my-library (includes: base-library, a, b)
```

But I can't figure out how to write the `package.json` in `my-library` to reflect this. So far, every permutation I've tried has resulting in me needing to explicitly install `a` and `b` in `app`.