# How to correctly handle PeerDependencies when working with a Components Libraries?

Tags: reactjs, npm, babeljs, create-react-app, final-form

First of all, thank you for reading and trying to understand this question.

In my team we have built a library for **common Components** with **React** for about 2+ years. This library is built with **Babel** creating two different transpilations. One in CommonJS for our Test Runner to run tests (because Jest cannot use ESM) and another one in ESM for Create React App (Webpack inside) to make [Tree Shaking possible](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/). We use [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) to build and develop our Apps.

This is working for us perfectly. But we have encounter a problem when managing [Final Form](https://final-form.org/react) Peer Dependencies (or any other library). This is our scenario:

- Common Components Library

  - PeerDependencies

    - Final Form
  - DevDependencies

    - Final Form
- App1

  - Dependencies

    - Common Components Library
    - Final Form
- App2

  - Dependencies

    - Common Components Library
    - Final Form
- App3 (It dont use FinalForm but it uses other Common Components)

  - Dependencies

    - Common Components Library

I'll explain this:

In our Common Components Library, which I spoke earlier, we have React Components that works with Final Form, like for example a **Vitaminated Autocomplete Text Input Component** that we share among many Apps. This Apps also use Final Form to create Components that implement forms locally for that App.

So App1 is right. Everything works fine. But for one thing, now if we want to upgrade Final Form version for this App because, lets say, we need a bug fix of Final Form. We are been forced to upgrade also our Common Components Library and the other App's Final Form version. We need to do this if we want to avoid execution errors within the **Final Form React Context**. If you are familiar with Final Form or React Context in general you probably have encountered this problem. You can't use different versions of a library that uses React Context. i.e: if we have final-form@1.2.3 in our Common Components Library and final-form@1.2.4 in our App1 it would genereate an execution error. So as I said, we are forced to upgrade not only on App1 and Common Component Library also on the other Apps that uses a Common Component on the Library that uses Final Form. The statement would be: 'Now, if we upgrade somewhere we have to upgrade everywhere'. And we don't want to do that. Probably we aren't handleling dependencies correctly.

So this drove us to move Final Form dependencies (we also use react-final-form, final-form-arrays, etc...) to **PeerDependencies**. Our problem was solved. But now, another one appeared when we saw that in Apps like App3 we were having an error when we build our App3 with Create React App. This is our output when using `npm run build`:

```
module not found `react-final-form' in file 'node_modules/CommonComponentsLibrary/VitaminatedAutoCompleteTextInput.js'
```

This means that, even with our App not using this VitaminatedAutoCompleteTextInput when we build its checking for every import in the `node_modules` so this is making us unable to build our App3. When we add the 'missing' depednencies to our App this builds with no problem and then when analyzing our bundle with `source-map-explorer` we see that final form depdenencies are not included in the bundle.

Is this necessary? I felt like we are missing something here. One solution for us has been including final form depdnencies on the Common Components Library as 'normal' dependencies but we were still having the first problem I mentioned before.

Maybe this problem is not only related with Create React App or Final Form. This is probably a more global isse within ESModules Libraries with Npm dependencies. Probably you will need me to enchance the explanation or have questions. I'll be glad to improve this question where needed. I have also searched on Google and here to find a similar question but I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35483805/install-peerdependencies-with-a-base-library). I dont know exactlcy if it's the same question but It have no answer yet.

Many thanks for trying to help or understand this issue,